# mySQL Query error can't update FROM Clause

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to use the following code to update my `post_title` column by removing the first word in it.

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_title = (
SELECT SUBSTRING(post_title, LOCATE(' ', post_title)+1) as post_title
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'post');
```

When using just this code

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(post_title, LOCATE(' ', post_title)+1) as post_title
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'post';
```

It doesn't give out any errors, and it shows a list of all the rows with everything updated, but when I go back to the table, nothing is actually updated. I'm assuming that's because this just selects all of the rows or something. That's why I tried the update code, which is not working and giving the following error

```
You can't specify target table 'wp_posts' for update in FROM clause
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: The error message says it all. You can't update and select in/from the same table in one SQL-call.

Comment: I realize as much, but I'm not well versed with mySQL hence why I ask for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should work.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title = SUBSTRING(post_title, LOCATE(' ', post_title)+1) WHERE post_type = 'post';
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Comes up with a syntax error. I think it was missing a bracket right in front of "SUBSTRING" so I added it, and still comes up with a syntax error highlighting `WHERE post_type = 'post')`

Comment: oh removing the end bracket seems to have fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  wp_posts a
        INNER JOIN wp_posts b
            ON a.post_type = b.post_type
SET     a.post_title = SUBSTRING(b.post_title, LOCATE(' ', b.post_title) + 1)
WHERE   b.post_type = 'post'
```

Comment: Comes up with this error `Column 'post_title' in field list is ambiguous`